# SQL query to get greatest distinct date - kind of

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables: articles and articletags

```
articles: id, author, date_time, article_text
articletags: id, tag

(article.id == articletags.id in a many-to-many relationship)
```

I am after the last time that something was published under each tag. To put it another way, for every tag, look through all the articles it is related to and find the most recent and return that.

eg
articles:

```
1, me, 12 Nov, Sometext
2, me, 13 Nov, Sometext
3, me, 14 Nov, Sometext
```

article tags

```
1, foo
1, bar
2, foo
3, bar
```

I want to get back:

```
foo, 13 Nov
bar, 14 Nov
```

I can get as far as an inner join and then am stumped. I dont think a DISTINCT clause is what I am after and I am not familiar enough for subqueries to know if that would help.

```
SELECT date_time, tag 
FROM articles, articletags
WHERE articles.id = articletags.id
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t.tag, max(a.date_time) as latest
from articles a
inner join articletags t
on t.id = a.id
group by t.tag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_time, tag 
FROM articles, articletags
WHERE articles.id = articletags.id
ORDER BY date_time DESC
GROUP BY tag
```

Comment: This actually ends up returning the oldest record, not the most recent. This is default behavior it appears, so it needs a max clause like Gorden Bell's solution has.

Secondly if you are using MySQL you need to swap Order By and Group by around for this to work. I dont know why but you do.

Comment: @Hyposaurus: the SQL standard says GROUP BY comes before ORDER BY.

Comment: @SoapBox: the trouble with this is that it returns all the rows, not just the max date row, for each tag.